# Add a "provide explanation to the answer" note in Help Center or FAQ

Tags: feature-request, answers, help-center

Yesterday I came across [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32601988/sum-the-numbers-in-a-string-in-oracle/78156800#78156800). It's code-only, and I commented that it would be better to provide some explanation to this answer. But the answerer *commented* the explanation, not added it to the post. Certainly, I can edit the post myself. But it would be (probably) better to add a note to "How do I write a good answer?" in the Help Center. I understand that users don't read long texts, but, at least, then we could provide a link to the Help Center saying "To create a better answer, please, provide an explanation to your code", or something like this.

Comment: You can fix this yourself by using unambiguous advice. `Please [edit] the answer to provide some explanation.` makes it clear how they are supposed to do it without even increasing the word count much.

Comment: The "how to answer" advice isn't written at a low enough level for things like "make sure to actually explain the code" to make sense in there. Even then it's already longer than the attention span of people who offer code-only answers. At any rate, people are certainly not going to look up and read the how to answer page just because you pointed out a low-quality answer - not unless you directly link it, and even then the success rate is quite low. Some people just can't be reached.

Comment: I usually leave a "canned" comment to these types of answers, something like, "I recommend that you avoid posting an answer that is mostly code with little to no explanation.  The best answers fully explain a proposed solution and the rationale behind it, using code to mainly buttress and illustrate concepts mentioned in the explanation. Doing this can help elevate both question and answer so that they are more helpful to future visitors to the site who come looking for solutions to similar problems, which is, after all, the main purpose of the site. "

Comment: The help centre already says "Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better.". In how far would a code-specific advice improve things? Where would you put such advice, seeing how there is no code-specific section already?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi you're right. I'll probably ask a "How much code is acceptable in an answer" question to further point to it and its answer.